# How do I access the ajax request data in the done/success ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a text input with a value which is constantly changing.

Each time the value changes, an ajax request.

Because the value of the text input is changing constantly, when an ajax request comes back successfully I want to determine if the current value of the text input is the same as the value that I sent in the ajax request data.

I don't see any examples showing how to access the request data from within the ajax done/success function.

How do I access the ajax request data in the done/success ajax function?

I could include the request value in the response data, but it seems that there should be a way to do this without updating an API.

Comment: it's the first argument of the callback function. people usually call it `data`.

Comment: If you create a function which accepts the input value as argument and performs the Ajax request, then you can access the value via the function parameter. Or simply assign the value of the input to a variable when you make the request, that should suffice.

Comment: @Derek: That's the *response*. OP is asking for the data sent via the request.

Comment: you want to access the request instead of the response data? why?

Comment: @Alp because " I want to determine if the current value of the text input is the same as the value that I sent in the ajax request data" entry is important for him i guess

Comment: on the client side you have te request data already. just save it before sending it away and reuse it when validating the response

Comment: been a long day, you're right @FelixKling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign the input value to a variable:

```
function makeRequest() {
    var value = myInput.value;
    $.ajax({
       // ...
       success: function() {
           if (value === myInput.value) {
               // ...
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly , try utilizing `input` `event` ? The value should always be different ? If requirement is to cache values , then determine if returned value different from one in cache , create a cache object ?

```
$(function () {
    var input = $("input");

    input.on("input", function (e) {
        $.post("/echo/json/", {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                "value": e.target.value
            })
        }, "json")
            .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }, function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown)
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eaq3x0ur/

Answer (score -1):

You should store the current input value in a variable and then simply check if it is equal to its current value. Since ajax requests are asynchronous, you can't store that value in a variable in this way

```
function sendRequest(inputValue){
    var currentValue = inputValue;
    $.ajax({ })
        .done(function(data) {
            // currentValue could be changed
        });
}
```

Instead you need to bind that variable to a [self invoking function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and then check if it is equal to your current input value into `.done`.

The following approach should work (not tested):

```
function sendRequest(inputValue){
    (function(val){
        $.ajax({
            // Your options
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if (val == $("#yourInput").val()) {
                // Do something..
            }
        });
    })(inputValue); // Pass 'inputValue' to self-invoking function as 'val'
}
```

Comment: I know your intentions are good, but what you are describing is incorrect in this particular scenario. In your first example, the value of `currentValue` (or `inputValue`) does not change, unless something *inside* the function itself does it. `currentValue` (and `inputValue`) is a local variable and thus cannot be changed from the outside. So, a self invoking function is not necessary, all you have to do is *not* reassign `currentValue` (or `inputValue`) in the function. There are scenarios where what you described is a problem, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I supposed that each time input value changes `sendRequest()` will be called and `currentValue` will change its value. Of course you can use the first piece of code, but in that case you can't call `sendRequest()` until ajax response is taken. That's all..

Comment: That's not true. There is no connection between local variables of two function calls. Every function call has its own separate environment. Try this simple example: `function sendRequest(inputValue) { setTimeout(function() { console.log(inputValue); }, 1000); }; sendRequest(21); sendRequest(42);` According to you, it should log 42 twice (but it doesn't).

Comment: You have right, I had a similar problem but in my case variable was created outside the function. Thank you for explanation.